# non-numeric argument binary operator error

Tags: r, gradient-descent

Not sure why I am getting a non-numeric argument binary operator error. Do I have some type mismatch going on?

```
   for (j in 1:length(theta)) {
      val = exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector) * y * random_data_vector[i])
      val = val / (1 + exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector)))
      theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha * val)
    }
```

Error:

```
Error in theta * random_data_vector : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Values:

```
> head(theta)
[1]  0.02435863 -0.74310189 -0.63525839  0.56554085 -0.20599967  0.43164130
> head(random_data_vector)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
> y
    V9437
785     1
```

After FIRST iteration of for loop, `theta` looks like this:

```
> head(theta)
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] -0.2368957

[[3]]
[1] 0.697332

[[4]]
[1] 0.6104201

[[5]]
[1] 0.8182983

[[6]]
[1] 0.7093492
```

For more information, the above is a snippet from my entire function I am trying to create around stochastic gradient descent.

`data` is a set of rows grabbed from a CSV
`labels` is 1 row grabbed from a CSV
`alpha` is a float

```
mnist = read.csv('mnist_train.csv', header=FALSE)
data = mnist[,mnist[nrow(mnist),]==0 | mnist[nrow(mnist),]==1, drop=FALSE]
labels = data[785,]
data = data[1:784,]

train = function(data, labels, alpha) {
  theta = runif(nrow(data),-1,1)
  decay_rate = .01
  random_column_indexes = sample(ncol(data))
  idx = 1
  limit = length(random_column_indexes)
  threshold = 1e-5
  delta = 1000000

  for (n in 1:ncol(data)) {
    if (delta <= threshold) {
      break
    }
    i = random_column_indexes[n]
    random_data_vector = data[, i]
    y = labels[i]
    previous_theta = theta
    for (j in 1:length(theta)) {
      val = exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector) * y * random_data_vector[i])
      val = val / (1 + exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector)))
      theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha * val)
    }
    alpha = alpha - decay_rate
    delta = abs(previous_theta - theta)
  }
  return(theta)
}
```

Comment: `theta` is a list, not a vector, so you might need to be using `unlist(theta)`.

Comment: Some issues I can see. 1) Build a reproducible example, since here is not much clear what kind of objects you are dealing with; 2) your loop is strange in a couple of ways: you loop over `theta`, but you use all `theta` inside the loop. Furthermore, sometimes `i` appears and other times `j` (maybe there is another outside loop?) 3) Your `y` looks like a `data.frame` and this coerces the result of operations into `data.frame`s and the assignments in a `list`. If `y` is just a single value, just extract it.

Comment: @nicola I've updated my question with more information. Hope it helps! Let me know if there is anything else missing

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you subset "labels" when entering it into the function. Are you sure that this is a vector? I know that subsetting tibbles, if done incorrectly, outputs another tibble.

Comment: @Fustin This is how I got the data http://dpaste.com/3QVEM6X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider that the problem has to do with the subsetting of your objects. From the [link](http://dpaste.com/3QVEM6X) you provided in the comments I see that your data is a data.frame object and you subset it using [. If you check the type of any data.frame e.g. `typeof(iris)` you can see that it is a "list".

When you use `y = labels[i]`, your object will be a list, that's because:

> when [ is applied to a list it always returns a list: it never gives you the contents of the list. To get the contents, you need [[   [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Declare `y` as `y <- labels[[i]]` or subset `labels` from your data.frame as a vector doing `as.numeric(data[785,])`